# Using PHP to submit a Vector onto MySQL to make a connection with 2 tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, http-post

i have a list of emails on a database, which are brought onto the screen, this is coming from a previous page where you choose the category to add emails into.
The idea is for the user to check in the emails he wants to add to a connecting table that will join those two.
But i seem to be having problems. I have tried editing the page where i think the problem is, which is the , but no clue as to how i should edit it.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("problema na conexao");
mysql_select_db("trabalho1");
$idcategoria = $_GET["id"];             
$query = "SELECT nome,email,id FROM email";
$results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());   
            echo"<center>";
            echo "<table border='2'>\n";
            echo"<form id='formulario' name='formulario' method='post' onsubmit='return validar(this);' action='../inserir/inserirmailcat.php'>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<button type='submit'>Submeter</button>";
            echo "<tr align='center'><td>Nome</td><td>Email</td><td>Adicionar a Categoria</td></tr>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {    
                foreach ($row as $campo=>$valor) {                              

                        if($campo=="nome")
                            {
                                echo "<td><b></b>".$valor. "\n</td>";
                            }
                        if($campo=="email") 
                            {
                                echo "<td><b></b>".$valor. "\n</td>";
                            }   
                        if($campo=="id") 
                            {
                                echo "<td><input name='nome[".$valor."]' type='checkbox' value='Adicionar'></td></tr>";
                            }
                                                }
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='categoria' value='".$idcategoria."'>";
                echo "</form>\n";
                                                            }
                echo "</table>\n";
                echo"</center>";
?>
```

This first page receives the ID from the previous one, and it lists a series of emails, where i check out the ones i want to add to a new table. And i try to pass them through a vector.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("problema na conexao");
mysql_select_db("trabalho1");

$queryq = "SELECT id FROM email";
$resultsq = mysql_query($queryq) or die(mysql_error()); 
    while ($rowq = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsq)) {  
                    foreach ($rowq as $campoq=>$valorq) {
    $cat = $_POST["categoria"];
    $username = $_POST['nome['.$valorq.']'];
        if ($username != '')
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO emailcategoria (email,categoria) VALUES ('".$username.",".$cat."')";
            mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        }
                                                        }
                                                }
mysql_query($queryq) or die(mysql_error());
header("Location:../listar/listarcategoria.php");
?>
```

On this second page i try to add only the emails which have been selected onto a new table which will receive the email's ID and the category's ID, but it is giving me the following error "after a few different error's when i tried a diferent approach":
Notice: Undefined index: nome[8445] in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\trabalho\inserir\inserirmailcat.php on line 10
The error is given for all the email ID's.
UPDATED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is on this like

```
$username = $_POST['nome['".$valorq."']'];
```

Firstly, is it supposed to be 'nome' ?

Secondly change the syntax like this

```
$username = $_POST['nome['.$valorq.']'];
```

Comment: I made that change. And i think it is supposed to be 'nome', since it's the name i applied to the input on the 1st page.
After the change, i got the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$valorq' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ']' in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\trabalho\inserir\inserirmailcat.php on line 10

Comment: Check the HTML output of this line.  `echo "<td><input name='nome['.$valor.']' type='checkbox' value='Adicionar'></td></tr>";`

Comment: On which page do you want me to try that? Still on the 1st or on the 2nd one?

Comment: On the first page browse to it and `View Source` and see what it outputs i think you might have and issue double quotes and single quotes. It pretty sure it need amending to  `name='nome[".$valor."]'`

Comment: The output is this for all emails:  
<td><b></b>amlobo
</td><td><b></b>amlobo@mail.telepac.pt             
</td><td><input name='nome['.8446.']' type='checkbox' value='Adicionar'></td></tr><input type='hidden' name='categoria' value='1'></form>

Comment: I did the ammends and aparently the output is showing he right email ID for the vector. But nothing's changed after ammending

Comment: If my answer is correct please mark it so. The issue was with the caps sensitive `$_POST['']` If you want assistance CSS or HTML tables you should probably separate that into a separate question that focuses on layout as it is difficult to respond to those in comments.

Comment: Your answer solved the problem at the time, altough i had other stuff after. But you helped alot. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = $_POST['nome['".$valorq."']'];
```

Well that's wrong, as the syntax highlighting shows.

```
$username = $_POST['nome['.$valorq.']'];
```

Also, sanitise your input or (better) use prepared statements!

[image: xkcd]
> xkcd

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I did that correction and got the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$valorq' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ']' in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\trabalho\inserir\inserirmailcat.php on line 10
Also, can you explain better about sanitising my input? Didn't quite get the idea, sorry :(

Comment: Clearly you didn't use the code I gave you. Show me your updated code.

Comment: Like I said, you didn't use the code I gave you. What's the point in helping if you're just going to not put the `.`s in there and then tell me the answer I gave you doesn't work?

Comment: WOW! Was a big fail on my part. I am sorry. Now it gives me the following error for all the ID values of my emails:
Notice: Undefined index: nome[8445] in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\trabalho\inserir\inserirmailcat.php on line 10

Comment: That's because your form creation is wrong. `echo "<td><input name='nome['.$valor.']'` should be `... name='nome[".$valor."]'`

Comment: I did that correction, and now it says it has an undefined index.   Updating page with the error